# Failed to create a session, as response has been committed. Unable to store SecurityContext

Tags: spring, spring-security

#### Summary

We have configured filterchain in applicationContext.xml file as mentioned below.

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant" >
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="requestContextFilter,securityContextFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,userRoleProcessingFilter" />
        </sec:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <bean id="requestContextFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter"/>

    <bean id="securityContextFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
         <property name="securityContextRepository">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository"></bean>
         </property>
         <property name="forceEagerSessionCreation" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter" >
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />
        </property>
    </bean>
     <bean id="userRoleProcessingFilter"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
                <property name="principalRequestHeader" value="CC_USER" />
                <property name="credentialsRequestHeader" value="CC_CRED" />
                <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
                <property name="continueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication" value="false" />
                <property name="exceptionIfHeaderMissing" value="false"></property>
                <property name="checkForPrincipalChanges" value="true"></property>
        </bean>
 <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager" >
        <property name="providers" >
            <list>
                <ref local="authenticationProvider" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.powerup.common.authorization.spring.xxx.AuthenticationProvider" >
        <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
            <bean class="com.powerup.common.authorization.spring.xxx.UserDetailsService">
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and web.xml is configured as shown below.

```
<web-app>
<!------->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>springSecurityFilterChain</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/remoting/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

#### Actual Behavior

Spring security is supposed to persist the sessions whenever there is a successful authentication request but in our case, it is not able to persist the session at times (this behavior is not consistent) and leading to creation of a new session which ultimately causes my application to go for actual authentication again. Please note that this behavior is inconsistent.

I am seeing below messages in spring security log file.

> 2016-05-10 09:41:22,042 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /remoting/ViewService at position 1 of 4 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestContextFilter'
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,042 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /remoting/ViewService at position 2 of 4 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,042 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] No HttpSession currently exists
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,042 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,042 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /remoting/ViewService at position 3 of 4 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,042 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /remoting/ViewService at position 4 of 4 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter'
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,042 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter] Checking secure context token: null
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,042 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter] preAuthenticatedPrincipal = snme, trying to authenticate
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,064 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider] PreAuthenticated authentication request: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken@6bc667b: Principal: snme; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@7798: RemoteIpAddress: 144.5.156.254; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,068 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter] Authentication success: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken@e031ed5f: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@35f133: Username: snme; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: UIM-User; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@7798: RemoteIpAddress: 144.5.156.254; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: UIM-User
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,068 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /remoting/ViewService reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,342 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] HttpSession being created as SecurityContext is non-default
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,342 WARN  [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] Failed to create a session, as response has been committed. Unable to store SecurityContext.
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,342 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] HttpSession being created as SecurityContext is non-default
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,342 WARN  [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] Failed to create a session, as response has been committed. Unable to store SecurityContext.
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,342 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] HttpSession being created as SecurityContext is non-default
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,342 WARN  [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] Failed to create a session, as response has been committed. Unable to store SecurityContext.
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,343 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter] Chain processed normally
>   2016-05-10 09:41:22,343 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
>   2016-05-10 09:41:23,254 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /remoting/LockingService at position 1 of 4 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestContextFilter'
>   2016-05-10 09:41:23,254 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /remoting/LockingService at position 2 of 4 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
>   2016-05-10 09:41:23,254 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] No HttpSession currently exists
>   2016-05-10 09:41:23,254 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
>   2016-05-10 09:41:23,255 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /remoting/LockingService at position 3 of 4 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
>   2016-05-10 09:41:23,255 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] /remoting/LockingService at position 4 of 4 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter'
>   2016-05-10 09:41:23,255 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter] Checking secure context token: null
>   2016-05-10 09:41:23,255 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter] preAuthenticatedPrincipal = snme, trying to authenticate

#### Expected Behavior

Had the context been successfully stored, it would not have unnecessarily gone for a new authentication request.

#### Version

**spring 4.0.6** and **spring security 3.2.4**

`spring-security-config-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar`  `spring-security-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar`  `spring-security-crypto-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar`  `spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar`

`spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution of spamming this log?